I need to use EF compiled query for performance optimization
I have controller endpoint which generates complex sql query. And this is my main app endpoint during start it is hit which loads around 500 items. The sql query generated as a sample is below, i am just putting a portion because this is very long query
SELECT [t].[Bk_ID], [t].[Md_AudioEn_ID], [t].[Md_AudioAr_ID], [m].[Md_URL], [m0].[Md_URL], [t].[Bk_Code], [t].[Bk_Name], [t].[Bk_Name_Ar], [t].[Bk_Title], [t].[Bk_Title_Ar], [t].[Bk_Introduction], [t].[Bk_Introduction_Ar], [t].[Bk_Summary], [t].[Bk_Summary_Ar], [t].[Bk_Characters], [t].[Bk_Characters_Ar], [t].[Bk_Desc], [t].[Bk_Desc_Ar], [t].[Bk_Language], CASE
    WHEN LOWER([t].[Bk_Language]) = N'arabic' THEN N'عربي'
    WHEN LOWER([t].[Bk_Language]) = N'english' THEN N'إنجليزي'
    ELSE N'الكل'
END, [t].[Bk_Trial], [t].[Bk_Active], [t].[Bk_CreatedOn], [a].[Us_DisplayName], [t].[Bk_ModifyOn], [a0].[Us_DisplayName], [m].[Md_ID], [m0].[Md_ID], [a].[Id], [a0].[Id], [t1].[Ct_ID], [t1].[Ct_Name], [t1].[Ct_Name_Ar], [t1].[Ct_Title], [t1].[Ct_Title_Ar], [t1].[Ct_Desc], [t1].[Ct_Desc_Ar], [t1].[c], [t1].[Ct_Active], [t1].[Ct_CreatedOn], [t1].[Us_DisplayName], [t1].[Ct_ModifyOn], [t1].[Us_DisplayName0], [t1].[c0], [t1].[c1], [t1].[c2], [t1].[c3], [t1].[Bk_ID], [t1].[Ct_ID0], [t1].[Id], [t1].[Id0], [t1].[Ct_ID1], [t1].[Tg_ID], [t1].[Tg_Title], [t1].[Tg_Title_Ar], [t1].[Tg_Desc], [t1].[Tg_Desc_Ar], [t1].[Tg_Total], [t1].[Tg_Summaries], [t1].[Tg_Categories], [t1].[Tg_Active], [t1].[Tg_CreatedOn], [t1].[Tg_Creator], [t1].[Tg_ModifyOn], [t1].[Tg_Modifier], [t1].[Ct_ID2], [t1].[Tg_ID0], [t1].[Id1], [t1].[Id00], [t3].[Gn_ID], [t3].[Gn_Title], [t3].[Gn_Title_Ar], [t3].[Gn_Desc], [t3].[Gn_Desc_Ar], [t3].[Gn_Total], [t3].[Gn_Summaries], [t3].[Gn_Authors], [t3].[Gn_Publishers], [t3].[Gn_Active], [t3].[Gn_CreatedOn], [t3].[Gn_Creator], [t3].[Gn_ModifyOn], [t3].[Gn_Modifier], [t3].[Bk_ID], [t3].[Gn_ID0], [t3].[Id], [t3].[Id0], [t4].[Pb_ID], [t4].[Md_ID], [t4].[Cn_ID], [t4].[Pb_Name], [t4].[Pb_Name_Ar], [t4].[Pb_Title], [t4].[Pb_Title_Ar], [t4].[Pb_Desc], [t4].[Pb_Desc_Ar], [t4].[Pb_Active], [t4].[Bk_ID], [t4].[Pb_ID0], [t5].[Th_ID], [t5].[Th_Title], [t5].[Th_Title_Ar], [t5].[Th_Desc], [t5].[Th_Desc_Ar], [t5].[Th_Summaries], [t5].[Th_Active], [t5].[Th_CreatedOn], [t5].[Th_Creator], [t5].[Th_ModifyOn], [t5].[Th_Modifier], [t5].[Bk_ID], [t5].[Th_ID0], [t5].[Id], [t5].[Id0], [t7].[At_ID], [t7].[Md_ID], [t7].[At_Name], [t7].[At_Name_Ar], [t7].[At_Title], [t7].[At_Title_Ar], [t7].[At_Desc], [t7].[At_Desc_Ar], [t7].[At_Active], [t7].[Bk_ID], [t7].[At_ID0], [t8].[Tg_ID], [t8].[Tg_Title], [t8].[Tg_Title_Ar], [t8].[Tg_Desc], [t8].[Tg_Desc_Ar], [t8].[Tg_Total], [t8].[Tg_Summaries], [t8].[Tg_Categories], [t8].[Tg_Active], [t8].[Tg_CreatedOn], [t8].[Tg_Creator], [t8].[Tg_ModifyOn], [t8].[Tg_Modifier], [t8].[Bk_ID], [t8].[Tg_ID0], [t8].[Id], [t8].[Id0], [t10].[Md_ID], [t10].[Md_FileType], [t10].[Md_Extension], [t10].[Md_Title], [t10].[Md_Title_Ar], [t10].[Md_URL]
.........

And this the part of code which is responsible for generating the above sql queries.

            public async Task<Result<PagedList<BookDto>>> Handle(Query req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _ctx.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s =>
                    s.UserName == _userAccessor.GetUsername() && !s.Us_Deleted, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                bool Subscribed = (user != null && user.Us_SubscriptionExpiryDate > DateTime.Now);

                string property = string.Empty;
                if (Subscribed) property = "Bk_Trial";

                var qry = _ctx.Books
                    .ProjectTo<BookDto>(_mpr.ConfigurationProvider, new { currentUsername = _userAccessor.GetUsername() })
                    .AsQueryable();

                

                #region Filter
                char[] Chars = new char[] { ' ', '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' };
                string Search = req.Params.Search;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Search)) {
                    Search = Search.ToLower();
                    List<string> SearchWordList = Search.Split(" ").ToList();

                    qry = qry
                        .Where(s => s.Bk_Name.ToLower().Contains(Search)
                            || s.Bk_Name_Ar.ToLower().Contains(Search)
                            || s.Bk_Title.ToLower().Contains(Search)
                            || s.Bk_Title_Ar.ToLower().Contains(Search)
                            || s.Bk_Desc.ToLower().Contains(Search)
                            || s.Bk_Desc_Ar.ToLower().Contains(Search)
   
                }

                string Language = req.Params.Language;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Language))
                {
                    Language = Language.ToLower();
                    qry = qry
                        .Where(s => s.Bk_Language.ToLower().Contains(Language));
                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Params.Status)) { 
                    switch (req.Params.Status.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "active":
                            qry = qry.Where(s => s.Bk_Active == true);
                            break;
                        case "disable":
                            qry = qry.Where(s => s.Bk_Active == false);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                #endregion
                #region Order
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Params.OrderBy))
                {
                    switch (req.Params.OrderBy.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "name":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Name);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Name);
                            break;
                        case "name_ar":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Name_Ar);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Name_Ar);
                            break;
                        case "title":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Title);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Title);
                            break;
                        case "title_ar":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Title_Ar);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Title_Ar);
                            break;

                        case "trial":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Trial);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Trial);
                            break;
                        case "language":
                            if (req.Params.OrderAs.ToLower() == "desc") qry = qry.OrderByDescending(s => s.Bk_Language);
                            else qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Language);
                            break;

                        default:
                            qry = qry.OrderBy(s => s.Bk_Title);
                            break;

                    }
                }


My question is, does compiled query helps in performance improvement of dynamically changed parameters? Microsoft suggest that compiled query is not possible for dynamically changed parameters here. In my mobile app first request is taking too much of time. and the parameters are fixed. The actual endpoint is like Cook/getCooks?search=&status=active&pageSize=1000&orderBy=Title&orderAs=DESC.

In your case it will not help. Compiled query speed is based on how EF Core finds translated query in it's cache. Even without CompiledQuery, it is fast.

The select part of the query is usually not that interesting in performance tuning. It's the joins that are the problem

Compiled queries help with the calculation of queries even if parameters are different, unless they result in a different query tree shape (like with select if x then select y else z). However, do keep in mind that the execution time of the queries on the database side is not affected by this.

Your primary issue is going to be your database indexing, not EF's cache. You also might want to think about why your table is so wide, perhaps it needs normalization. And maybe think about joins, and AsSplitQuery(). Also instead of using ToLower set your columns to case-insensitive collations.

This is known as a "kitchen sink" query. Databases find this reqlly difficult to optmise. This could be yout problem. But first address the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/78475212/1690193 which seems to indicate that you are sucking all the data over to the client.

Compiled queries are a micro-optimization.  You need to find bigger issues.  The biggest issue with this is that you're projecting into a DTO too early.  This
                var qry = _ctx.Books
                    .ProjectTo<BookDto>(_mpr.ConfigurationProvider, new { currentUsername = _userAccessor.GetUsername() })
                    .AsQueryable();

Will ensure that all the Books are fetched to the client, converted to BookDtos and all the additional query logic will happen on the client.
Instead add all the query logic to _ctx.Books, and project the results to BookDto as the last step.

Thanks David and others for their wonderful insights. I will update asap
